# Objective C - No previous prototype for function

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, warnings, function-prototypes

I have 2 methods that are giving me a warning:

```
id LoadObjectFromFile(NSString* filename) {
    if ((filename = DocumentPath(filename, NO))) {
        return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile: filename];
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

BOOL saveObjectWithFile(NSString* filename, id object) {
    if ((filename = DocumentPath(filename, YES))) {
        return [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject: object toFile: filename];
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

This is giving me a "No previous prototype for function" warning.

I'd rather not just disable the warnings in xcode.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to write functions, or methods? These are different things in objective-c

Comment: That warning is horribly useless. I always turn it off.

Comment: @WTP: It's not useless. Using a function before you've declared it puts you at risk of an implicit type mismatch. For example, any use that precedes the declaration will assume it returns `int`, so if the function returns `float`, you will get a garbage result (since the real return value is in a different place). This is why you must declare your functions before you use them, as the warning reminds you.

Comment: Even though I have declared method on .h, It gives the warning on the definition in .m file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this are C functions not objective C methods. have you defined them in the .h file?

Comment: don't worry that kind of errors are the most difficult to spot ;)